# How to trigger validation with a button click

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox

Upon instantiating my program, I have a textbox that already has a red border around it indicating that validation has already been triggered.  I would only like the validation triggered once the user has inputted something in the textbox.  This works in my other textboxes, I'm just wondering if this only happens because the binding mode is OneWayToSource, and if so, how would I be able to change this behavior to my other textboxes?

Comment: Please provide the Xaml for the textbox binding. Usually any difference in behaviour is due to UpdateSourceTrigger.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using WPF? If so your object needs to implement IDataErrorInfo. You can then tell the textbox when it should show the error. eg:

```
    string System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (columnName.ToLower())
            {
                case "code":
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Code)) return "Required field";
                    break;
                case "name":
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Name)) return "Required field";
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```